# Python: convert UTC time to JTC(Asia/Tokyo) time and get the hour

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I want to convert the UTC time(date1 = 'Wed Nov 23 04:01:52 +0000 2016') to JTC time, the code is following:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import timezones
from dateutil import tz


date1 = 'Wed Nov 23 04:01:52 +0000 2016'
p_date = re.compile(r'[+-]([0-9])+')
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('Asia/Tokyo')
date_str_new = p_date.sub('', date1)
date_str_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str_new, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print(date_str_obj)
utc = date_str_obj.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
tokyo_time = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
print(tokyo_time)
```

The result is following:

```
 2016-11-23 04:01:52
 2016-11-23 13:01:52+09:00
```

Although the time is converted to JTC (Asia/Tokyo) time, but I don't want '+09:00' which is following the time.I mean I just want to the datetime form: 2016-11-23 13:01:52 to get the day, hour data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(tokyo_time.replace(tzinfo=None))
print("hour: " + tokyo_time.hour)
```

Comment: thanks for your @hoozecn answers, I have checked your method which meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you manipulate the `tokyo_time` as a string? If so, you could just write

```
tokyo_time  = str(tokyo_time).split('+')[0]
```

Comment: I know use the rex or split to delete +09:00, but how to get the hour after the tokyo_time is a string.

Comment: You said "*...I just want to the datetime form: 2016-11-23 13:01:52 to get the day, hour data...*", if you need just the hour:min:sec you can proceed with string manipulation:`tokyo_time = str(tokyo_time).split('+')[0].split()[1]`. If you need it as a `datetime` object you can 1) convert the string back through `datetime.strptime()` but you of course will loose the timezone info or 2) if you need to change *only the visualization* (the ouput of the `print` function) you can subclass `datetime` and reimplement the `__repr__` function in order not to show the delta time

Comment: thanks for your @Matteo Furlan kind response! sorry for my missing information. Anyway, thanks for your time and consideration!